# Avoid printing output in mongo client

Tags: mongodb

I am working with mongo client. Sometimes the output of some commands I execute involve an enormous output, which mongo prints on screen. How can I avoid this?

Comment: With the query? or when starting mongo?

Comment: Doesn't work. I just checked, the output is printed anyway.

Comment: Just set the return value to a local variable: `var x=db.so.find();` and inspect it as needed.

Comment: You will need to provide more concrete example of the type of output you are talking about. And whether you want any output from the commands or just running for their side effect.

Comment: @WiredPrairie comment solved the problem. I am not deeply familiar with JavaScript. I just needed to put a `var` before the variable name to suppress the output.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a way to suppress output. 
Using `"var x = ...;`" allows to hide output of expressions.
But there are other commands that harder to suppress like

```
Array.prototype.distinct = function() {
   return [];
}
```

This produces printing of new defined function.
**To suppress it** you will need to write it in this way:

```
var suppressOutput = (
   Array.prototype.distinct = function() {
      return [];
   }
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Per the comment by @WiredPrairie, this solution worked for me:

Just set the return value to a local variable: `var x=db.so.find();` and inspect it as needed.